# Rails API using Devise for authenticaion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, devise

I set up a rails API and I am using devise for the user auth and the front end is all done in Angular.  What is the best way to manage state between calls when using Devise with just an API?

Comment: I don't want to be rude or anything but have you tried googling it? First result for 'angular devise': https://github.com/cloudspace/angular_devise, second result: https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/posts/authentication-with-angularjs-and-ruby-on-rails

Comment: I dont know what was going wrong with my search but I somehow never came across this but it looks like its exactly what I need.  Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Here are some open-source projects that may help you:

- https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth
- https://github.com/cloudspace/angular_devise